# How can I exit a subprocess that calls a django server?

Tags: python, django, server, subprocess, port

I am running an otree erperiment on a django server on localhost:8000 and I want to run a subprocess that starts another django server on 8080. 
The browser tab will not open if in first order the subprocess is called. How can I fix this?
How can I quit the new server (and the browser tab) and go back to my first one?

This is for an oTree experiment. During this experiment, I need to open another django project, specially I want to run a django-oscar shop.

```
class MyPage2(Page):

    def before_next_page(self):
       os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'shop.settings'
       subprocess.call(['py', 'shop2/manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:8080'], shell=True)
       webbrowser.open('http://localhost:8080', new=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this a little differently.
I have waived the sub processes and have created an API with django REST framework instead. Passing parameters back and forth (and working within the same browser tab) were imho the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is exact u want, but if u want terminate a subprocess, simply call `os.killpg` as below:
Try below code, replace `call` with `Popen`

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

# The os.setsid() is passed in the argument preexec_fn so
# it's run after the fork() and before  exec() to run the shell.
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid) 

os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)  # Send the signal to all the process groups
```

Comment: I need to terminate the second server (8080) and close the new browser tab. But os.setsid doesnt work on windows. I tried some alternatives like process.kill() but my second django app (the oscar shop) cannot find the process that I started from my first django app (the otree experiment).